# Where to cause initElements method using FindBy annotation

Tags: testing, webdriver, pageobjects, findby

I'm trying to use page object model but I'm not sure how to init elements correctly.

Please see an example of my test class:

```
public class TestSuiteSubscriber extends TestInitializer {
Menu menuPage = new Menu(driver);
SubscribersSearchForm searchForm = new SubscribersSearchForm(driver);


@Test     (priority = 1)
public void findByOldNumber(){
    menuPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Menu.class);
    menuPage.openSubscribers();
    searchForm = PageFactory.initElements(driver, SubscribersSearchForm.class);
    searchForm.subscriberNumber.sendKeys("100001");

}
```

If I cause .initElements in constructors of page classes, I get the NullPointerException. As I understand, this is because they had been initialized before the page is loaded. Is there a proper way to avoid causing the .initElements method directly in the test method to make tests more readable?

Answer (score 0):

A very common practice of instantiating the elements using *PageObject* is to use a *BaseClass* and inherit that throughout the other page classes. So the `initElements` will be instantiated every time the *PageObject* is instantiated. I have [GitHub](https://github.com/safrrhmn/SeleniumTestNG/blob/master/src/PageObjects/PageObjectHelpers/BaseClass.java) where I implemented the concept with *TestNG*. See if that would help you.

In your case `TestInitializer` should have the `initElements` I believe. This line should reside in `TestInitializer` constructor

```
PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help: http://screencast.com/t/zejcVaeM2M
If I put the initialization method into constructor of the class, I get the null pointer error. And if it is right before impacting the elements (commented on the screenshot), it is okay.

Comment: @BohdanN Is TestBase is the base? Sorry, really hard to understand without knowing the full flow